# having trouble using bundles

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, webpack, webpack-2

i have a web app on my local computer, for now all the code is on the same index.js file.

i want to split the code to a several files, i understand the best way is to use libraries like **require.js** or **webpack** etc..

and use `import` to import the splitted **js files**

the thing is that after two days of intense reading the documentation i just cant figure how to make the bundles work

> *information*: **editor**: vs code , **syntax** es=6 babel , webpack:v2.0.0

would someone be nice and explaine me how to configure webpack localy so i can use import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found great explanation guides in youtube  highly recommend anyone who have trouble with understanding webpack to try and lern from here [webpack introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYo7YymudpE&t=1s)

Answer (score 0):

best was to use classes and import your depenent classes using require.
You can also use typescript which will convert your code into any version of javascript.

#### ES2015 or above

```
//class1.js

class class1 {

... all your methods
}

//class2

require('class1');
class class2 {

... all your methods
}
```

#### typescript

in typescript tsc will bould your typescript and bundle it into one file as the way you want like umd, es2015, es2016, etc

you can also configure it with webpack to put sugar on it.

```
//class1.js

export class class1 {

... all your methods
}

//class2

import { class1 } from 'class1';
export class class2 {

... all your methods
}
```